# Unexpected result while executing list.pop()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, variable-assignment

I'm trying to assign a = x and b = x.pop(); Albeit I'm getting unexpected assignments. Could you explain this?

```
>>> x = [10, 11, 12, 13]
>>> a, b = x, x.pop(2)
>>> print a
[10, 11, 13] # Shouldn't I get a = [10, 11, 12, 13]?
>>> print b
12
```

Comment: `x` is mutable.  `a = x`, `x` changed, and therefore so did `a` since they point to the same thing.

Comment: This is the correct result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types)

Comment: @StephenRauch I am fairly beginner in python. I didn't know about mutable and immutable objects. The other questioner seems to know about that already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a = [10,11,13], b = 12.

A value of x pops out after you execute 'b = x.pop()' and x changes forever i.e for the rest of the program after executing value 'b'

Answer (score 4):

> Since you're referring direct list, it's popping and assigning what
>   left in list. If you have list as copy then try this:-

```
x = [10, 11, 12, 13]
a,b = x.copy(),x.pop(2)
print(a) # your expected output
```

Comment: Sequences can be copied by slicing instead of x.copy(), so it can be done by x[:]. Python FAQ [https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python]

Comment: @Matt.St agreed

Answer (score 0):

When you say *a=x*, both *a* and *x* are pointing to the same list, therefore modifying *a* will also modify *x*. If you say *a*=list(*x*)
then *a* will be a separate copy of the list *x*.